# If $C_1$ has a radius of $10cm$ then show that the sum of the areas of all these circles is $\frac{25π}{3\sqrt2-4}cm^2$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

> **QUESTION:** Let {$C_n$} be an infinite sequence of circles lying in the positive quadrant of the $x$-$y$ plane with strictly decreasing radii and satisfying the following conditions. Each $C_n$ touches both $x$ and $y$ axis. Further for all $n≥1$ the circle $C_{n+1}$ touches the circle $C_n$ externally. If $C_1$ has a radius of $10cm$ then show that the sum of the areas of all these circles is $\frac{25π}{3\sqrt2-4}cm^2$.

**MY APPROACH:** Since circles have decreasing radii it's quite clear that the sum of areas will be finite. Area of $C_1=100π$. The I tried to find out the area of the second circle. Let radius of $C_2=r$. Then, $2(10-r)^2=(10+r)^2$, since distance between centres=sum of their radii. Solving the above I find that $r=30-20√2$. Now I thought I would get some relation in areas from which I can convert this sum into an infinite GP. But I cannot solve it..

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Note

$$OA = \sqrt2 r_1 = r_1 + r_2 + \sqrt2 r_2$$

leading to the ratio $\frac{r_2}{r_1} = (\sqrt2-1)^2 =a $. Likewise $\frac{r_3}{r_2}=\frac{r_4}{r_3}=…=a$. Thus, the total  areas is of a geometric sum

\begin{align}
S &= \pi(r_1^2 + r_2^2 + r_3^2 + … ) 
= \pi r_1^2(1+ a^2+ a^4 + a^6 + … ) \\
& = \frac{\pi r_1^2}{1-a^2}=\frac{100\pi}{1-(\sqrt2-1)^4} = \frac{25\pi}{3\sqrt2-4}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

To obtain a recursion relation, you need to start with a general radius $r_n$ for circle $C_n$ and solve for $r_{n+1}$, the radius of the inscribed circle $C_{n+1}$.  To this end, we see that $$r_n (\sqrt{2} - 1) = r_{n+1} (\sqrt{2} + 1).$$  This gives the desired recurrence and the common ratio.